# can someone suggest to me how to distribute an app

Tags: xcode, app-store

I am trying to distribute an app for a friend that has already created a distribution certificate on his mac, how do I upload the app for him, because every time I download the certificate it doesn't come with a key (the gray icon key). What do I do?I believe the gray key is the private key.

Answer (score 0):

You need [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com). Register there, and send invitation to email of your friend. He will have to open the email in his device and follow instructions. After Your friend will register his device, it will be possible for him to download and install applications from TestFlight site.

Answer (score 0):

The private key can't be downloaded.  It has to be exported from the keychain of the Mac that was originally used to request the Certificate from Apple.